# Laravel Password & Password_Confirmation Validation

Tags: laravel, validation, passwords

I've been using this in order to edit the User Account Info:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'min:6',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|same:password|min:6'
]);
```

This worked fine in a Laravel 5.2 Application but does not work in a 5.4 Application.

[image]

What's wrong here, or what is the correct way in order to only make the `password` required if either the `password` or `password_confirmation` field is set?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can use the [confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-confirmed) validation rule.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
    'email' => 'email',
    'vat_number' => 'max:13',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
]);
```

Comment: For those who could not get this work, use this link for documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: `confirmed` validation rules for the latest Laravel 7.x https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Answer (score 84):

Try doing it this way, it worked for me:

```
$this->validate($request, [
'name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
'email' => 'email',
'vat_number' => 'max:13',
'password' => 'min:6|required_with:password_confirmation|same:password_confirmation',
'password_confirmation' => 'min:6'
]);`
```

Seems like the rule always has the validation on the first input among the pair...

Comment: Actually, `same:password` rule should be in `password_confirmation`, not password

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6'
```

Comment: There is no need of `'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6'
`

Comment: it is not required as it will validate the confirm password automatically,

Answer (score 9):

try confirmed and without password_confirmation rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
        'email' => 'email',
        'vat_number' => 'max:13',
        'password' => 'confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
```

Comment: Does `confirmed` also ensures that it's the same value? Because, from the documentation I only see that there must be a `xyz_confirmation` field present, although I may be wrong.

Comment: I hope so, I use confirmed in my app too

Comment: From Laravel 5.4 docs: `confirmed` `The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input.`, where matching means that the field is present and it's the same

Comment: yeah they have to be the same

Answer (score 6):

I have used in this way.. Working fine!

```
 $inputs = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required | min:6 | max: 20',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required| min:4| max:7 |confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required| min:4'
  ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

I have used in this way. Its Working fine!

```
$rules = [

            'password' => [

                    'required',

                    'string',

                    'min:6',

                'max:12',             // must be at least 8 characters in length

                ],

            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password|min:6'

        ];
```

Answer (score 5):

Very easy in Laravel 9

For Laravel 9.x, here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-confirmed , and **below code is what works for me:**

```
public function store(){
    $signUp = request()->validate([
        'student_email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        *'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:7|max:255',*
    ]);
```

**Notes:**

In your form.blade, ensure that the password input field has a name attribute of `name="password"` -> **it has to be password** ,

- Also, add an attribute of `name="password_confirmation"` to the *Confirm Password text input* box, and it will work.
- This reduces the code in the form request validation method of the
  store.
- and there was no need to add `Password_confirmation` name attributes
  to your validation request method in the controller.

Cheers...

Answer (score 3):

It should be enough to do:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'sometimes,min:6,confirmed,required_with:password_confirmed',
]);
```

Make password optional, but if present requires a password_confirmation that matches, also make password required only if password_confirmed is present

Answer (score 0):

Note when using the second code you will have to import the Rule class
Also added the student_class just to show you how to call the unique in both cases

```
public function store(Request $request){
$signUp = $request->validate([
    'student_email' => 'required|email|max:255',
    'student_class' => 'required|unique:student,student_class'
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:7|max:255'
]);
```

// this is another way you can write it and it will still run

```
public function store(Request $request){
$signUp = $request->validate([
    'student_email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255'],
    'student_class' => ['required', Rule::unique('student', 'student_class')],
    'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', 'min:7', 'max:255']
]);
```