# I have a paasword and a confirm password field i have validated it using laravel but even the password is same for both field it shows not match?

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css

> this is my controller file, validating  the registration form, i have used laravel and MySQL as database using laradock as an environment

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
    
     $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|max:255|distinct',
      'username' => 'required|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
      'password' => 'required|same:password_confirmation',
    ]);
    
      User::create([
          'name' => $request->name,
          'username' => $request->username,
          'email' => $request->email,
          'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
      ]);
    
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
```

> this is my blade file's password and confirm password field

Password

```
                    @error('password')

                    <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                        {{ $message }}
                    </div>

                    @enderror

            </div>

            <div class="mb-4">
                <label for="password_confirmation" class="`sr-only`">Password `Confirmation</label>`
                <input type="password" name="passsword_confirmation" id="password" placeholder=" repeat Your password"
                    class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg" value="">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line as below

```
'password'       => ['required', 'confirmed']
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, still having the same problem password don't match even it is same.

Comment: @prasunregmi, Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623841/laravel-password-password-confirmation-validation

Comment: sorry to say, don't know why none of the methods in that page worked for me.Don't know whats the problem.

Comment: @prasunregmi, Please check one by one validation with and without validation password