# Password confirmation does not match in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to implement a registration form using livewire but I get a validation error that password does not match, where is the problem?

my livewire

```
public $name;
public $email;
public $password;
public $businessName;
public $passwordConfirmation;
public function createUser(){

        $this->validate([
            'name'=>'required|max:100',
             'email'=>'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|min:8|confirmed',
            'passwordConfirmation' => 'required ',
        ]);
        
        $data=[

            'name'=>$this->name,
            'email'=>$this->email,
            'password'=>Hash::make($this->password)
        ];
        return User::create($data);
    }
```

and my view

```
<div class="row mb-3">
   <label for="password"  class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password" wire:model='password'  type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
      @error('password')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
      </span>
      @enderror
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-3">
   <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password-confirm" wire:model="passwordConfirmation"  type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

password_confirmation you need to add in the validation

i.e, example

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'required',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|same:password|min:6'
]);
```

But you used different keyword for the field name "passwordConfirmation".

Ref https://techvblogs.com/blog/password-and-confirm-password-validation-in-laravel#google_vignette

Ref : [Laravel Password & Password_Confirmation Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623841/laravel-password-password-confirmation-validation)